# Cover page with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, covers

How can I design the following cover with latex?

[image]

Comment: You should ask something you don't know how to do rather than ask “Do it for me questions”. What is what you don't know how to do? Positioning text? Change the color? Scale it?

Comment: @Manuel Maybe giving the OP some ideas in comments could get him started like TikZ for the background.

Comment: @Manual I can design background, "TeX" and "LaTeX" with Tikz. But I can't design "&" and it's shadow as you see in the picture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option using the best of two worlds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% for running it with pdflatex -shell-escape
\usepackage{pst-light3d}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\definecolor{myblue3}{RGB}{81,91,199}
\definecolor{myblue2}{RGB}{66,76,103}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{112,121,139}

\newcommand\MyAmpersand{%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(8,2)
\DeclareFixedFont{\Rmb}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{2cm}
\PstLightThreeDText[
  linecolor=white,
  fillstyle=solid,
  fillcolor=myblue3,
  LightThreeDAngle=-30,
  LightThreeDYLength=-0.25,
  LightThreeDColorPsCommand=%
    2.5 div 0.7 exch 0.8 sethsbcolor
  ]{\Rmb \&}
\end{pspicture}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[mygray]
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east) --
  ([yshift=1.3cm]current page.east) to[out=195,in=-15]
  ([yshift=3cm]current page.west) --
  cycle;
\fill[myblue2]
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east) --
  ([yshift=3cm]current page.east) to[out=195,in=-15]
  ([yshift=3cm]current page.west) --
  cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}  
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\node[
  align=left,
  font=\color{white}\fontsize{58}{64}\bfseries,
  anchor=north
  ] 
  at ([yshift=-2.3cm]current page.north)
  (name) 
  {\TeX \\[0.3ex] \LaTeX};
\end{pgfonlayer}  
\begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
\begin{scope}[scale=3,transform shape]
\node[] 
  at (name.west)
  {\MyAmpersand};
\end{scope}  
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Compile using

```
pdflatex --shell-escape
```

(or its Windows equivalent). Make some adjustments to fonts, sizes, etc as required.